# Sphinx: "no module named compat"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Our Travis CI tests just started breaking randomly:

https://travis-ci.org/Gallopsled/pwntools/builds/343962397

With the error message:

```
Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.autoprogram (exception: No module named compat)
```

It appears that the issue is that one of our Sphinx dependencies relies on deprecated functionality: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/autoprogram/issues/1

How can I work around this?

Comment: Exact same issue here: https://readthedocs.org/projects/mosfit/builds/6776530/

Answer (score 2):

We can dynamically re-inject the module and its contents with the code below, by putting it in the Sphinx `conf.py`:

```
try:
    import sphinx.util.compat
except ImportError:
    import sys
    import types
    import sphinx.util
    import docutils.parsers.rst
    class compat(types.ModuleType):
        Directive = docutils.parsers.rst.Directive
    sphinx.util.compat = compat('sphinx.util.compat')
    sys.modules['sphinx.util.compat'] = sphinx.util.compat
```

Comment: I created a pull request to fix this issue upstream: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/autoprogram/pull/2